# podAntiAffinity does not work with nodeAffinity

Tags: kubernetes

I have series of deployments on k8s that deploys same server binary but different in spec like memory limit, etc. each deployments only 1 pod to run, and want to schedlule pods for these deployments so that each VMs are only scheduled single pod.

because some deployments require larger memory than others, we combine nodeAffinity and podAntiAffinity to satisfy following requirement.

- every type of instances will be assigned only single pod which has label `pod_group_affinity` == `per_node`
- each pod that has different memory requirement correcty assigned to the node that has corresponding memory size

below is my configuration.

```
    spec:
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: node.kubernetes.io/instance-type
                operator: In
                values:
                - ${INSTANCE_TYPE}
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - labelSelector:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: pod_group_affinity
                operator: In
                values:
                - per_node
            topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
```

I first tried with local minikube as single VM (with giving proper node.kubernetes.io/instance-type value), but pods of all deployments are scheduled. it should not happen because all pods have pod_group_affinity == per_node label. even I remove nodeAffinity part, still podAntiAffinity does not seem to work.

am I missing something? for example, podAntiAffinity does not work for inter pods from multiple deployment? but as long as I read the article https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#more-practical-use-cases , podAntiAffinity can refer the label of pods from another deployment.

regards,

EDIT: I added more information to investigate the reason, due to the suggestion of @confused genius.

- `kubectl get nodes --show-labes`

```
$ kubectl get nodes --show-labels
NAME       STATUS   ROLES                  AGE     VERSION   LABELS
minikube   Ready    control-plane,master   4d19h   v1.22.2   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,kubernetes.io/hostname=minikube,kubernetes.io/os=linux,minikube.k8s.io/commit=0a0ad764652082477c00d51d2475284b5d39ceed,minikube.k8s.io/name=minikube,minikube.k8s.io/updated_at=2022_01_19T12_04_46_0700,minikube.k8s.io/version=v1.23.2,node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane=,node-role.kubernetes.io/master=,node.kubernetes.io/exclude-from-external-load-balancers=,node.kubernetes.io/instance-type=Standard_B2ms,topology.hostpath.csi/node=minikube
```

I manually set `node.kubernetes.io/instance-type=Standard_B2ms` to emurate real environment which each VM has label of corresponding instance type.

- template part of deployment
  due to NDA of the work, I cannot put real version of deployment, but it is almost like below.

```
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ${NODE_NAME}
      pod_group_affinity: per_node
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ${NODE_NAME}
        team: backend
        release: stable
        environment: ${ENV_LABEL}
        pod_group_affinity: per_node
    spec:
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: node.kubernetes.io/instance-type
                operator: In
                values:
                - ${INSTANCE_TYPE}
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - labelSelector:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: pod_group_affinity
                operator: In
                values:
                - per_node
            topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"                
      initContainers:
      - name: registration
        image: ${REGISTRATION_CONTAINER_IMAGE}
        env:
          - name: PASSWORD
            value: "${PASSWORD}"
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        command: ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/workdir/run.sh"]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: node-config
          mountPath: /workdir/run.sh
          subPath: run.sh
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "${MEMORY_REQUESTS}"
            cpu: "${CPU_REQUESTS}"
          limits:
            memory: "${MEMORY_LIMITS}"
      containers:
      - name: web
        image: ${WEB_CONTAINER_IMAGE}
        env:
          - name: USERNAME
            value: "${USERNAME}"
          - name: PASSWORD
            value: "${PASSWORD}"
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: rest
          protocol: TCP
      - name: cordapp
        image: ${NODE_CONTAINER_IMAGE}
        env:
          - name: QUEUE_REGION
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: ${NODE_NAME}-config
                key: QUEUE_REGION
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        command: ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/workdir/run.sh"]
        lifecycle:
          postStart:
            exec:
              command: ["/workdir/lifecycle.sh", "startup", "${GRACE_PERIOD_SECONDS}"]
          preStop:
            exec:
              command: ["/workdir/lifecycle.sh", "shutdown", "${GRACE_PERIOD_SECONDS}"]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 10000
          name: rpc
        volumeMounts:
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "${MEMORY_REQUESTS}"
            cpu: "${CPU_REQUESTS}"
          limits:
            memory: "${MEMORY_LIMITS}"
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: ${GRACE_PERIOD_SECONDS}
      volumes:
      - name: ${NODE_NAME}-config
        configMap:
          name: ${NODE_NAME}-config
```

Comment: Please upload ``` kubectl get nodes --show-labels ``` and also template section of your deployment as well  so that we can get more clarity.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I added information that you required.

Answer (score 8):

I could solve the problem.

The reason that above settings do not work well is I put each deployment in different namespace, as described in https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#inter-pod-affinity-and-anti-affinity

Final yaml will look like:

```yaml
      podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - labelSelector:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: pod_group_affinity
                operator: In
                values:
                - per_node
            topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
            # this setting is important
            namespaces: ["node1", "node2", "node3"]
```